# Embedding flex items within flexbox grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with creating grid in flexbox according to following image layout. I spent two days figuring out how to solve it without making position:absoulte hacks. Can someone please help me to sort it out with flex good practise?

[image: flex layout as image]

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us your code.

Comment: Have you tried `display: grid` and work using that? Flexbox is uni directional, grid can easily get you layout that you want.

Comment: show code of what you have.  make it a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a pro concerning flexbox, but Rikin seems right. Grid is way better for layouts like this.

In flexbox, you would have to put flex-container into flex-container, to get the layout you want. Try my code below and you will get the idea. You'd have to figure out the middle column on the left by yourself, though.

Cheers!

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="col-left">
<div class="col-left-row-1 color green">
  Lorem 1
</div>
<div class="col-left-row-2 color yellow">
  Lorem 2,3,4
</div>
<div class="col-left-row-3 color  red">
  Lorem 5
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-right color blue">
  Lorem 6
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 500px;
  color: darkblue;
}
.col-right {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}
.col-left {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 3;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
.color {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Hi @langer-197 , thx for code snippet. I added 2,3,4 boxes in following snippet: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxzebb. It works great. thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it worked for you!